# Matlab matrix product

Tags: matrix

Hello I have an error on mathlab product with matrix(MATHLAB 2016), i've this code:

```
A=[1 1 0 0;2 1 0 0;-5 -4 -3 -2;0 0 0 -2];
C=[0 1 0 1]; 
X=A*C;
```

**ERROR IS:**
Error using  * 
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your A matrix is 4x4 and your C matrix is 1x4

To be able to perform a matrix product C must be 4x1

Two way to solve the issue

- Transpose C using '
- Write C the correct way

Working code with transposition :

```
A=[1 1 0 0;2 1 0 0;-5 -4 -3 -2;0 0 0 -2];
C=[0 1 0 1]; 
X=A*C';
```

Working code with C set the correct way :

```
A=[1 1 0 0;2 1 0 0;-5 -4 -3 -2;0 0 0 -2];
C=[0; 1; 0; 1];
X=A*C;
```

**For reviewers: I am asking myself if this question belongs here or simply if this question is useful. The question is on basic matrix mathematics and is fully illustrated in the matlab documentation under matrix product.**